# Concatenating strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe below:

```
id                  sub      status      description
313                 AF       open        test
234                 JF       open        testing in progress
919                 IA       closed      test
is completed
                 well done
393                 QE        open       failed testing
888                 VE        open       check the
test results
before closing
193                 UR        open       waiting
```

Due to formatting, some of the description are split into new rows in different columns (either id or sub). I would like to concatenate these back into the original row.

What the end result will look like:

```
id                  sub      status      description
313                 AF       open        test
234                 JF       open        testing in progress
919                 IA       closed      test is completed well done
393                 QE       open        failed testing
888                 VE       open        check the test results before closing
193                 UR       open        waiting
```

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Thank you.

Edit:
Tested g

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    NaN
12    NaN
13    NaN
14    NaN
15    0.0
16    0.0
17    0.0
18    NaN
19    NaN
20    0.0
21    0.0
22    0.0
23    0.0

Name: id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify groups - here is used [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with `join` for column `description`:

```
g = df['id'].str.isdigit().cumsum()

#another idea for groups
#g = pd.to_numeric(df['id'], errors='coerce').notna().cumsum()

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'first')
d['description'] = ' '.join

df = df.replace('', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
    id sub  status                            description
0  313  AF    open                                   test
1  234  JF    open                    testing in progress
2  919  IA  closed            test is completed well done
3  393  QE    open                         failed testing
4  888  VE    open  check the test results before closing
5  193  UR    open                                waiting
```

Test groups:

```
print (g)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    5
8    5
9    6
Name: id, dtype: int32
```

Another solution with join no `id` rows first to `description` column and then aggregate:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['id'], errors='coerce').notna()
g = m.cumsum()

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'first')
d['description'] = ' '.join

df.loc[~m, 'description'] = (df[~m].replace('', np.nan).stack()
                                   .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join))
df = df.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(d)
```

Comment: Hi jezrael. I tested the code in my original data but the outcome is not correct. the DF only returned 1 row, and all the columns (except the last, which is description) returns `is completed`. In `description` column, it concatenate all the strings instead, for example using my above example, it returned `is completed test results before closing`. It also ignored the strings if it exist in `sub` column.

Comment: @user3118602 - Are numeric data in `id` column like in question? Because seems difference in real data, so is created only one group.

Comment: Hi Jezrael. The original dtype is `object`. I used ` pd.to_numeric(df[id'], errors='coerce').astype(int)` to convert it to int but returned error `IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` since I have some nulls in the `id` column.

Comment: @user3118602 - I add ouput of `print (g)` to answer, in your solution got same different numbers? Or same number `1` ?

Comment: I updated my original post with `print(g)` results. This is without using any `pd.to_numeric`.

Comment: @user3118602 - seems you forget for `.notna()` like `pd.to_numeric(df['id'], errors='coerce').cumsum()`, need `pd.to_numeric(df['id'], errors='coerce').notna().cumsum()`

Comment: My bad. Tested it and mostly work. However, the string in column `sub` did not concatenate `well done`. How could I modify the code to include it? Thanks.

Comment: @user3118602 - Hmmm, so some columns are concatenate to `sub` column and some to `description` ? How distinguish it?

Comment: @user3118602 - In data sample are columns `id` and `sub` concatenate to `description`, in real data not?

Comment: Hi Jazrael, you are right. I was doing testing using both the sample provided in my post and my real data. The sample works using your code, but somehow the `sub` is not working. I checked the dtypes and they are all `objects`. I tried to replace my original data with other strings but it still doesn't concat. I noticed one thing for this particular data in `sub`. The next column to `sub` is called `status`. For this row, the `status` is empty instead of `NaN`. I tried to use `df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)` to make it `NaN` but it didn't work. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @user3118602 - exactly, but I think edited answer should working.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Just one last question, why does the code require NaN and what could have possibility caused this one case to have a blank instead of NaN?

Comment: @user3118602 because `ffill` function forward filll first non NaNs values, so if no replacement is used last non NaN value, in problematic row is used it.